# DO I have to use __strong keyword?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I saw someone use the following

```
__strong static foo *_foo = nil;
```

I am wondering if __strong is needed here; I mean __strong is the default? is that right?

Comment: It is the default behavior.  Maybe they were using the strong keyword to send the message: "I'm using strong on purpose."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since a strong reference is the [default](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226), you are correct.